# Leave numbers when removing duplicates

Tags: python

This is my code for removing duplicate letters in a string

```
word=input()

def dup_find(word):
    empty = ""  
    for character in word:
        if character not in empty or character == " ":
            empty = empty + character
    return empty
```

When input is "6969 macaroni" the output is "69 macroni" but I want the numbers to be left alone and only remove the duplicate letters so: 6969 macroni.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just change your if statement to `if letter.isdigit() or (letter not in x or letter == ...):`

Comment: Actually it should be `if letter.isdigit() or letter not in x ...`

Comment: What about valid words which have duplicated letters, such as `book`, or words which have duplicated letter sequences, such as `barbaric`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way

```
text="Enter string:"+" "
string=input(text)

def rem_duplicates(string):
    x = ""  
    for letter in string:
        if letter.isdigit() or letter not in x or letter == ' ':
            x = x + letter
    return x

print(rem_duplicates(string))
```

Comment: Hi so is there any difference between using isdigit or isnumeric when identifying the numbers?

Comment: `isdigit()` checks for if character is in range 0-9 no matter number or string but `isnumeric()` will also check the type of the string

Answer (score 1):

Check the letter coming from the string `isnumeric()` or not then set your condition. `letter == ' '` is not required but you can set also.

```
text = "Enter string:"+" "
string = input(text)

def rem_duplicates(string):
    x = ""
    for letter in string:
        if letter.isnumeric() or letter not in x or letter == ' ':
            x = x + letter
    return x


print(rem_duplicates(string))
```

Comment: It prints "Enter string:" and a space followed by your input

Comment: @Dav_DidHu text is for user choice. Doesn't need at all but in the question, text is mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = "Enter string: " # just do the space in the string
string = input(text)


def rem_duplicates(string):
    x = ""
    for letter in string:
        if letter.isdigit() or letter not in x or letter == " ": # if the string is a number or letter is empty or letter not in x
            x = x + letter
    return x


print(rem_duplicates(string))
```